error: could not lock config file C:/Users/Lina/.gitconfig: No such file or directory
Настраиваю git, при попытке выполнить команду
git config --global user.name "name"
выдает ошибку error: could not lock config file C:/Users/Lina/.gitconfig: No such file or directory
Подскажите как решить проблему

Попробуйте у себя в домашней папке C:\Users\Lina\ вручную создать пустой файл с именем .gitconfig
